# Define the following group action in terms of matrix representation and show its differentiable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, absolute-continuity

I don't have much idea about groups acting on sets and so I have been having trouble trying to approach such kind of questions.  If i have group $G$ = $GL$($V$) and the space $S$ of symmetric bilinear forms of V( a finite dimensional $ℝ$-vector space)

The question says the action $G \times S \to S$ can be defined in terms of matrix representation and that it is differentiable. Now this means that the general linear group $GL$($V$) is acting on the space $S$ If i am not wrong. But I am having troubles in understanding the concept of differentiability of this action. And how will i represent this action in terms of matrices ? Edited: symmetric bilinear forms on V can be represented by symmetric matrices but but not sure how ?
any explanations? hints or diagrams will be very helpful.

Comment: Symmetric bilinear forms on a finite-dimensional vector space can be represented by symmetric matrices. What is the group action, explicitly?

Comment: @TedShifrin that was confusing to me as well. I was given this question without an explicit group action. I thought maybe I didn't understand the action here. but i am assuming  if i got this right,  $GL(V)$ is acting on the space of symmetric bilinear forms by left multiplication

Comment: Nope, that’s not an action. Try it! You need a symmetric answer!

Comment: @Ted Shifrin,  there are so many actions that i am unware of but now what clicks into my mind is this action defined by $S$ -> $A$$S$$A^T$ where $A$ belongs to $GL_n$(R) ?? Is this the right definition of the action?? the matrix multiplication gives symmetric result!!

Comment: Yes, that would be the action I'd expect. You can verify that it satisfies all the requirements of a group action.